# Problem with computing the elliptic integral of first kind

Tags: python, math

So, I am trying to compute the series expansion of the [elliptic integral of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Complete_elliptic_integral_of_the_first_kind), but I get different values when I do it via the series or when I use the scipy.special.ellipe function.I think there is something wrong with the code because as far as I know the series expansion I am using is correct.

```
import math 
from scipy.special import ellipe 
##Function for double factorial
def df(n):
    if n < 0:
        raise ValueError("El doble factorial no está definido para números negativos.")
    if n == 0 or n == 1:
        return 1
    return n * df(n - 2)


## Elliptic integral using series
def elipticintegral(a,b):
  m=((b**2-a**2)/b**2)
  suma=0
  for i in range(1,10):
    suma=suma + (((df((2*i)-1))/(df(2*i)))**2)*(m**i)
  x=((math.pi)/2)*(1+suma)
  
  return(x)

a=1
b=2
m=((b**2-a**2)/b**2)

print(ellipe(m))
print(elipticintegral(1,2))
```

And I got this:

```
1.2110560275684594
2.1475724285802786
```

Comment: What did you expect to get?

Comment: I’m way out of my depth here, but you say that you want to compute an elliptic integral of the *first* kind, while the scipy docs say that `ellipe` computes an integral of the *second* kind.

Answer (score 3):

As Ture Pålsson perceptively pointed out, you are computing a power series for an elliptic integral of the first kind, yet comparing it with scipy's elliptic integral of the second kind. You need `ellipk`, not `ellipe` for a direct comparison with your power series.

When computing functions as power series, never explicitly calculate factorials or double factorials. They grow too fast and you are repeating the same multiplies over and over again. Write each term as a simple multiple of the previous one.

Also, use a reasonable convergence criterion, not a fixed number of terms.

```
import math 
from scipy.special import ellipe, ellipk

TOL = 1.0e-10


## Elliptic integral of the first kind using series
def K( m ):
    n = 0
    term = 1.0
    sum = term
    while abs( term ) > TOL:
        n += 1
        term *= ( ( 2 * n - 1.0 ) / ( 2 * n ) ) ** 2 * m
        sum += term
    return 0.5 * math.pi * sum
  

## Elliptic integral of the second kind using series
def E( m ):
    n = 0
    sum, term, facs = 1.0, 1.0, 1.0
    while abs( term ) > TOL:
        n += 1
        facs *= ( ( 2 * n - 1.0 ) / ( 2 * n ) ) ** 2 * m
        term = facs / ( 2 * n - 1.0 )
        sum -= term
    return 0.5 * math.pi * sum
  

a, b = 1.0, 2.0
m = ( b ** 2 - a ** 2 ) / b ** 2

print( "Elliptic integrals of the first kind:" )
print( "scipy: ", ellipk( m ) )
print( "power series: ", K( m ) )

print( "\nElliptic integrals of the second kind:" )
print( "scipy: ", ellipe( m ) )
print( "power series: ", E( m ) )
```

Output:

```
Elliptic integrals of the first kind:
scipy:  2.156515647499643
power series:  2.1565156470924665

Elliptic integrals of the second kind:
scipy:  1.2110560275684594
power series:  1.2110560279621536
```